# Matlab PCA order of principal components

Tags: matlab, statistics, pca, numerical-analysis

So I read the documentation on pca and it stated that the columns are organized in descending order of their variance. However, whenever I take the PCA of an example and I take the variance of the PCA matrix I get no specific order. A simple example of this is example:

```
pc = pca(x)
```

Which returns

```
pc =

0.0036   -0.0004
0.0474   -0.0155
0.3149    0.3803
0.3969   -0.1930
0.3794    0.3280
0.5816   -0.2482
0.3188    0.1690
-0.1343    0.7835
0.3719    0.0785
0.0310   -0.0110
```

Meaning column one should be PC1 and column two should be PC2 meaning var(PC1) > var(PC2), but when I get the variance this is clearly not the case.

```
var(pc)

ans =

0.0518    0.0932
```

Can anyone shed light into why the variance of PC1 is not the largest?

Comment: Can provide the dimensions of and describe `x`?

Comment: It is 3X10 vector though I have used other sets of data and the same thing happens. After checking the latent values those were in order so I did find it strange that PC1 did not have more variance than PC2. In fact, when I used  428x18 matrix. The result was the same the latent seemed to agree with the order of the PC's, but the variances were in no particular order.

Comment: The variances of the first output `COEFF` or the variances of the second output `score`?

Comment: But also if it's just a 3-by-10 vector then you should include it in your question to make it replicateable

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) state that calling

```
COEFF = pca(x)
```

will return a *p*-by-*p* matrix, so your result is rather surprising (**EDIT:** *this is because your x data set has so few rows compared to columns (i.e. similar to having 10 unknowns and only 3 equations)*). Either way when they talk about variance They don't mean the variance of the coefficients of each component but rather the variance of the `x` data columns after being projected on to each principal component. The docs state that the output `score` holds these projections and so to see the descending variance you should be doing:

```
[COEFF, score, latent] = pca(x)
var(score)
```

and you will see that `var(score)` equals the third output `latent` and is indeed in descending order.

Your misunderstanding is that you are trying to calculate the variance of the *coefficients of the principal component vectors*. These are just unit vectors describing the direction of the hyperplane on which to project your data such that the resulting projected data has maximum variance. These vectors ***ARE*** arranged in an order such that *your original data projected onto the hyperplane that each describes* will be in descending order of variance, but variance of the projected data (`score`) and ***NOT*** of the coefficients of the principal component vectors (`COEFF` or in your code `pc`).